# Getting "incorrect number of arguments" when omitting parameter with default values in scala

Tags: scala, default-value

For a call to the following constructor:

```
class SparkContext(
    val master: String,
    val appName: String,
    val sparkHome: String = null,
    val jars: Seq[String] = Nil,
    val environment: Map[String, String] = Map())
  extends Logging {
```

In the following notice the last parameter is commented out:

```
val spark = new SparkContext("localhost", "GroupBy Test",
  System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), Seq(System.getenv("SPARK_EXAMPLES_JAR")) /* , Map() */)
```

Then the scala compiler (2.9.2) complains:

```
not enough arguments for constructor SparkContext: (master: String, appName: String, sparkHome: String, jars: Seq[String], environment: scala.collection.Map[String,String])spark.SparkContext
    val spark = new SparkContext("localhost", "GroupBy Test",
                ^
```

When it is uncommented, then the code compiles.   So .. what is wrong here AFA omitting the last parameter (and scala using the default value) ?

**Note I am on 2.9.3**

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Scala 2.10.3 and I copied and pasted your code to REPL, but the code ran without error. (just with modification at extends Logging)

Comment: I am on 2.9.3 i think that's the difference (see @Vidya)

Comment: Unfortunately, @Naetmul, the latest version of Spark only works with 2.9.3.

Comment: I'm not a spark user, but what version of spark? The ctor changed from 0.6 to 0.7 to 0.8. How are you building? 0.6 lacks defaults.

Comment: Well, I see from your other thread that you solved your compilation problem.  Would be nice if you zapped this question if it is spurious, or answered it if there's an interesting solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this error when trying to use one major version (first + second number) of the Scala compiler and a different version of a library, e.g. 2.9 compiler vs. 2.10-compiled library. Unfortunately, Scala-compiled libraries are not binary compatible between 2.8, 2.9, or 2.10, nor between different minor versions of 2.8 (different third number). In other words, all of your Scala libraries, as well as your code itself, have to be compiled with the same major version, and in the case of 2.8.x, with the same minor version as well. Binary compatibility does exist between minor versions starting with 2.10, and in most cases with 2.9, although there are some edge cases in the 2.9 series.

Comment: I am compiling with 2.9.3  against spark libraries that advertise 2.9.2.

Comment: "Binary compatibility does exist between minor versions (different third number)." Only starting with 2.10! 2.9.* are _almost_ binary compatible with each other (there are some edge cases, if I remember correctly), and 2.8.* aren't binary compatible.

Comment: In that case you shouldn't see this problem unless this is one of the "edge cases" mentioned by Alexey, which seems doubtful (it would hardly be an edge case). However, you should verify that you're really using 2.9.3, and that you're not using *any* 2.10-series libraries. If you found the answer as @som-snytt mentioned above, can you post it? You can answer your own question.